# Is there a way to stop Google Chrome from dynamically changing the font size of tabs?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

So my question isn't how to change the size of all the tabs which seems to be asked a lot.  My issue is that occasionally Chrome will decide to make the font size smaller of tabs that have really long titles.  Best described via screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of issue]

As you can see the tab furthest right has much smaller text.

Also two other notes: I am using Windows 7 and Chrome version is 24.0.1312.57 (Official Build 178923) m.

Comment: Please specify which version of Chrome? It is shown in `about:`.

Comment: @DanD. 24.0.1312.57 (Official Build 178923) m